# Print column with AWK

Tags: text-processing, awk, string

I am trying to find a way to use awk to start printing only once it finds the search parameter and print only a couple of columns following it.

To try to explain a little better I am looking over a log file that prints a lot of information as a single line. I want to take and extrapolate only certain aspects of that line. IE there's a big file with this line somewhere in it:

blahblah blah blah there is a lot of information here for name: John Doe and it just keeps on going and doesn't stop.

I want it to search for name and only print out:

name: John Doe

I know I can use the column segment, but I don't actually know where in that line name will be in different files.

Comment: How will you be able to tell then, which word is the name?  There might be multiple names, too, or no names on a line?

Comment: Why not use `grep -o` for this?  `grep -o 'name: ([A-Z][a-z]* )*' /path/to/input`

Comment: There is always going to be a name listed somewhere within the file and inside of the long line of just dumped information from a database. It will also only contain one name as it is just the name for the individual database table. Ultimately, there is a lot of good information in these files that is just poorly formatted and I am trying to create a quick bash script I can run on those logs so that it is in a more reader friendly format.

Comment: @DopeGhoti The point is, if he knows *which* name he's looking for, then he doesn't even have to search: he can just display it.  His question is, how can he discern that single name from `a lot of good information`.  I mean, will it always be prefixed by `name:`?

Comment: @Alex Yes, it's always going to be prefixed by name. I don't know what the name will be when I start looking though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest answer would NOT involve `awk`.  It would use `grep`, to output any matches of the word "name", and up to two words that follow:

```
grep -o 'name [A-Za-z]* [A-Za-z]*' filename
```

The `-o` switch includes only the parts that match, not the entire line; and the `[A-Za-z]*` tells that you are asking for a single word.

Let me know if you prefer to do this in `awk`-- but that would be much more complicated.

Comment: I'm glad-- I wasn't entirely sure whether this was what you wanted, from your post...

Comment: `awk` would not really be that much more complicated:  `awk /name [A-Z][a-z]* [A-Z][a-z]*/ { print substr( $0, RSTART, RLENGTH) }' inputfile`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Hmm, I wasn't aware of the `/ string /` functionality.  In fact, it doesn't seem to work on my machine...  As your quote is written, it's a syntax error; if I add an opening single quote before `/name`, it yields no results; if I put the opening quote before `{ print`, I get the error `awk: non-terminated regular expression and... at source line 1`

Comment: I omitted what to search _in_.. the syntax is `awk /regex/ ~ $0 { code to run if present }` to search the entire line.

Comment: OK, apparently both the `BSD` and the `GNU` `awk`'s find the match, but do not recognize the `RSTART` and `RLENGTH`-- hence, they printed nothing, and I was not aware that search functionality was present in `awk`. Using the `match` function explicitly did set those variables though. If you wish to post this as an answer, I will upvote it.

Comment: awk `RSTART,RLENGTH` works only for the explicit `match(...)` function as in DopeGhoti's separate answer but not for a regexp as a pattern or the `~` operator.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done with `awk`:

```
$ awk 'match( $0, /name [A-Z][a-z]* [A-Z][a-z]*/ ) { print substr( $0, RSTART, RLENGTH ) }' /path/to/inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

**Perl** solution:

`perl -lne '/(name:\s+\w+\s+\w+)/ and print $1'`

- `\s` matches whitespace characters (whitespaces per see, tabulations, etc.)
- `\w` matches letters and numbers
- `-lne` means don't print anything (n), except when print is used, output a newline in the end (l) and execute (e) the following

So the whole line will match name: followed by one or more whitespace character and one or more letter, again one or more whitespace character and one or more letter, and will then print that.